# Finding Distances in Spatial Query - ArcGIS Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am running a spatial query based on a buffered location (e.g. user clicks map, point is buffered and points from feature layer are queried within buffer).  Has anyone run something similar but also been able to calculate the distance between the clicked point and each queried location?

I can use the [Distance Params](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/distanceparameters-amd.html) to get the distances but they are ordered differently than the query output which defeats the purpose.

I need an output which has each point within the buffer and the distance to each point from the click point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [Lengths](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/SDK/REST/index.html?lengths.html) operation on the geometry server to submit a series of simple polylines constructed from your clicked point and your feature points.

You may have to project your clicked point into the spatial reference of your feature points, but once you've done that, you can make a line out of the two points.

The Lengths operation returns results that correspond to the order of submitted geometries.

Comment: The problem with this is the same as using Distance, there are no attributes returned with the Lengths output to join with the spatial query output.

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the original (ordered!) features then too, and assign the results of the Lengths operation to those features as a new attribute.